# is it possible to start coda slider on a hidden div?

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

i have a div id=holder, and inside a coda slider. it works alright, but to avoid the flickering in certain browsers, i decided to make holder display:none, and then display:block on $(document).ready

The problem is that, for some reason, when the parent div is display:none, the coda slider doesnt have any effect.

any workarounds or ideas for this issue? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all the z-indexes are set properly.  Also instead of display none, try making it 'invisible' by for example setting borders to 0; background color to white etc.

Comment: i end up applying: visibility:hidden; and when the doc is read, visibility:visible. The canvas occupies the same space but the whole thing inside doesnt flicker anymore. thanks!